# Need help adding popup info windows to polygons on Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to add popup windows to a leaflet map which shows buffer zones around different mining sites. When I click on a buffer zone polygon, I'd like to get the mine name information. Here's my code,

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Buffer Zones around Mine</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ height: 100% }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

  var map = L.map('map').setView([45, -95], 4); //center map view


  var CartoDB_Positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
subdomains: 'abcd',
maxZoom: 19
}).addTo(map); 

// load JSON data
 $.getJSON("BufferPolygons.json",function(data){
    // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
  });

//get popup info
var myLayer = L.geoJson(polygon, {
onEachFeature: yourOnEachFeatureFunction
}).addTo(map);

function yourOnEachFeatureFunction(feature, layer){
if (feature.properties.mine_name) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.mine_name);
    }
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to Leaflet and Javascript, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: My cursor changes when scrolling over polygons vs. non-polygons, so I believe information is being retrieved with a mouse click. Since nothing is displaying I'm assuming this is an HTML/CSS issue, perhaps that I haven't created any window for this information to go into?

Answer (score 2):

The polygons that you are seeing displayed are the ones created within the `$.getJSON` callback function. When you define `myLayer` outside of the callback, it appears to be looking for a `polygon` object that is undefined, so that layer and its popups are never created.

There are a couple ways to solve this. The most straightforward way is just to set the `onEachFeature` option for the `L.geoJson` that you create within the callback:

```
$.getJSON("BufferPolygons.json",function(data){
  L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: yourOnEachFeatureFunction
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

However, doing it this way, you may not be able to refer to that layer elsewhere (for instance, if you want to add it to a layer control), because it will not be created until `BufferPolygons.json` finishes loading. The better option in most cases is to create `myLayer` with whatever options you want, but without any data, and use the [`addData` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-adddata) to populate this empty layer in the callback function:

```
var myLayer = L.geoJson(false, {
  onEachFeature: yourOnEachFeatureFunction
}).addTo(map);

$.getJSON("BufferPolygons.json",function(data){
  myLayer.addData(data);
});
```